# Trouble understanding a SQl Query with MVC and C# and Web API

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I just can't seem to find the answer for what I am trying to do.

SQL database with a table that has VisitIndex and TypeIndex as two of the columns. I have wired an MVC entity controller to it. So,in the Web API controller I have GetVisit below working to grab records with that visitindex (its the key) , but GetVisit2 is not - won't compile as I am missing something. Its the line thats starts with Visit v = db. and the query, should be obvious that I want the records that have both id's specified. I might be going about it the wrong way?

Any, all help appreciated!

```
// GET: api/Visits/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Visit))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetVisit(int id)
    {
        Visit visit = db.Visits.Find(id);
        if (visit == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(visit);
    }
    // GET: api/Visits/id/typeindex is what i want (or similar)
    [ResponseType(typeof(Visit))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetVisit2(int id, int typeIndex)
    {
        Visit v = db.Visits.Where(f => f.VisitIndex == id && f => f.TypeIndex == typeIndex).SelectMany(f => f.Visit); //.Select(f => f.TypeIndex == id);   //.ToList();
        if (v == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(v);
    }
```

Comment: `.Where(f => f.VisitIndex == id &&  f.TypeIndex == typeIndex)`

Answer (score 0):

You want only 1 'Visit' Object. Also you're LINQ syxtax if off. So try something like this:

```
Visit v = db.Visits.FirstOrDefault(f => f.VisitIndex == id && f.TypeIndex == typeIndex);
```

If the combination of 'VisitIndex' and 'TypeIndex' is not unique as I assumed. 
Change the code like this:

```
List<Visit> v = db.Visits.Where(f => f.VisitIndex == id && f.TypeIndex == typeIndex);
```